# Bisecting dashed curved lines ala Threat Model

Tags: graphviz

Is there a way to add a curved dash line similar to the one present [here](https://online.visual-paradigm.com/app/diagrams/#diagram:proj=0&type=ThreatModelDiagram) for Privilege Boundaries?  I'd like to have a threat model checked into GIT that is procedurally generated as part of my CI/CD builds as apposed to drawing it online or in some tool like OmniGraffle and exporting image only to loose the original docs.

Comment: The link lead to a blank canvas

Comment: @sroush It is a blank canvas.  On the left are the possible elements you can drop...the red dashed line is for "Privilege Boundary".  That's what I am trying to simulate.  It's a red dashed bisecting line that separates one section from another.

Comment: Best guess: probably.  But you have not provided any "this is what I want" images or "got this far" Graphviz code, so it is impossible to say yes or no.

Answer (score 1):

You can get **fairly close** by adding some extra edges and invisible nodes and using attribute for extra edge [`arrowhead=icurve`](https://graphviz.org/doc/info/arrows.html), but it will **not be a dashed line**. Graphviz allows you to draw [dashed cluster boundaries](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U5iwy.png), or dashed edges from node to node, but the perpendicular line to the one or two edges will be impossible to draw without manual positioning, as you drawing it online, and as I assume you need to draw without human involvement.

Also with some extra effort with PostScript you can create [half-drawn nodes with dashed border](https://graphviz.org/doc/info/shapes.html#sdlshapes) like `A -> Internet Boundary [shape=yourshape color=red] -> B`, but this is also not actually a line crossing.

Image:
[image: Threat Model diagram with Privilege Boundaries made with graphviz dot]
and script for `arrowhead=icurve` variant:

```
digraph threat_model {
    graph [
        splines=false
        ranksep=0
        nodesep=2]
    User [shape=box xlabel=<<FONT COLOR="ORANGE"><B>Actor</B></FONT>>]
    a [shape=circle label=<<FONT><B>a. Static<BR/>front-end<BR/>files</B></FONT>> xlabel=<<FONT COLOR="ORANGE"><B>Process</B></FONT>>]
    b [shape=circle label=<<FONT><B>b. App<BR/>back-end</B></FONT>> xlabel=<<FONT COLOR="ORANGE"><B>Data<BR/>Flow</B></FONT>>]
    // Two extra nodes:
    boundary_User_b_1 [shape=point height=.01]
    boundary_User_b_2 [shape=point height=.01]
    
    User -> a [minlen=3 dir=both xlabel="1. Retrieve static\nfront-end files"]
    
    // Three extra edges:
    User -> boundary_User_b_1 [minlen=3 dir=back xlabel="2. Modify report"]
    boundary_User_b_1 -> boundary_User_b_2 [arrowhead=icurve arrowsize=6 color=red headlabel=<<FONT COLOR="RED">Internet<BR/>Boundary</FONT>>]
    boundary_User_b_2 -> b [minlen=3]
}
```

Another fairly close variant using [cluster](https://graphviz.org/docs/attrs/cluster/), note that the arrow can rest against boundary, with the [`compound=true`](https://graphviz.org/docs/attrs/compound/) attribute for graph  and [`lhead`](https://graphviz.org/docs/attrs/lhead/) attribute for arrow:
[image: boundary dashed cluster line made with graphviz]

```
digraph {
    graph[
        ranksep=1
        compound=true
    ]
    A
    B
    subgraph cluster_IB {
        graph [
            label="Internet Boundary"
            fontcolor=red
            margin=20
            style="dashed, rounded"
            color=red
        ]
        C   
    }
    A -> C
    B -> C [lhead="cluster_IB"]
}
```